# How to make underscore tag compatible to all browsers

Tags: html, xml

I am using html control attributes in an xml file like below

```
 <p>
    The quick <u><a href="http://querty.com/" target="_blank"></a>brown fox jumps </u> over the lazy dog.  
</p>
```

I am highlighting the http://querty.com link with an underscore tag. But the underscore to the link is not visible in all the Internet explorer browser versions(not works in IE11, works in IE8). Is there any way to use the underscore tag to support all the browsers.

Comment: How about using CSS or an inline style attribute? Also, your <a>tag should enclose the text you want linked</a>.

Comment: Ok I will try with it and comeback!

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think 'u' tag should work for IE 11.
I'm not sure why it doesn't work.
If it doesn't work I think u need to use following css.

```
u{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a css tag, or specify inline css.

Also, ensure `<a>` tag surrounds the text that you want linked.